# флешка которая при загрузке с неё автоматически устанавливала бы на комп несколько систем с заранее определёнными параметрами

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, usb, установка

Мне нужна флешка которая при загрузки с неё автоматически устанавливала бы сначала виндус 10 потом несколько дистрибутивов линукс. 
Помогите разобрать задачу и выявить главные трудности для её решения.

Comment: по поводу остального изложенного в тексте вопроса: я бы рекомендовал начать с попытки автоматически установить два дистрибутива gnu/linux. данная более узкая задача и так слишком нетривиальна, чтобы дополнять её ещё и практически неразрешимой. // и, да, ни моя память, ни поисковики, не выдают каких-либо следов о попытках сделать даже и более узкую задачу. вы, судя по всему, будете первым, кто её поставит и решит.

Comment: Будьте реалистами требуйте невозможного. Эрнесто Гевара

Comment: если железо однотипное, то можно просто распаковать готовую копию диска. dd в помощь (или какой нибудь акронис)

Comment: KoVadim dd мне нравится, но не совсем понимаю как дд будет взаимодействовать с биос

Comment: ну, загрузится с флешки, это Вам нужно будет обеспечить самому. Тут уж никак. Но потом просто перезаписываем весь диск готовым образом.

Comment: На винду же есть средства развертывания? И на линукс есть скрипты для автоустановки. Но надо три флешки, а не одну

Comment: KoVadim ну загружусь я с флешки, а дальше что, я не понимаю предложенный тобой алгоритм, мне чё вручную dd управлять?

Comment: eri вот типо токого я себе и представлял, но не совсем понимаю зачем три флешки, почему нельзя ограничиться одной

Comment: и что будет управлять последовательностью действий после загрузки флешки